# Jersey: The mysql java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver although inclueded

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jersey, server-side

I am trying to send GET request from the postman chrome plugin and I am getting this error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` I have already included the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin` in my project

jersey endpoint:

```
@Path("/test")
public class Driver{

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public void mysqltest(){
        Database db = new Database();
        db.connection();

    }
}
```

Database class:

```
public class Database {


    public  void connection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("jar works :) ");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have already  tested it with this class in the same project and I am getting the output `driver works`

Driver class:

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        connection();
    }

    public static  void connection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("driver works :) ");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Why when am I calling it from the jersey method I am getting the error in the title?

Comment: If it's a web application, make sure the jar is places inside WEB-INF/lib. Otherwise, add the jar explicitly in the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to what @LuiggiMendoza wrote, you need to understand the packaging of your artifacts and trace the classloader delegation to understand if the classloader that invokes your `Driver` class also has access to the MySQL driver JAR. For instance, adding the MySQL JAR to WEB-INF/lib *may* not help if Jersey is a dependency of an EJB JAR that itself is in the WEB-INF/lib of the webapp.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following dependency in your pom.xml file. (I assume you are working with Maven project)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.39</version>
</dependency>
```

P.S. I was getting the same exception. This worked for me.